# SQL Server VS Need to dump my database to a bak file

Tags: sql-server, database

In Visual Studio, I have a database file connected to local db. However I need to make a dump file (`.bak`) of this database in order to bring it online on my provider that accepts only such files.

From the "Explore Objects of SQL Server" window in VS I find no option to do that.
I have such option in SQL Server Management Studio, but I am not able to make it see my database. How can I move the database to SQL Server Management Studio in order to make the dump file? Or is there any other option?

Comment: Why can't you see the database in Management Studio? How are you connecting to the server? The server used by Visual Studio should be `(localdb)\ProjectsV13` (the number varies by Visual Studio version). From a command line, you can use `sqllocaldb` to list all the instances. Connect  to them using the `(localdb)\<instance>` syntax. (Running a manually written `BACKUP` query from a VS database window is also an option, but not as convenient.)

Comment: I do not know why in management studio I cannot see. I can only see databases created there. Do you know how to write such query for backup?

Comment: [The docs know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql#backing_up_db). If that won't work either, your database may not be attached while your code is not running (if you're using the `AttachDbFileName` in your connection string). If that's the case, you can simply attach the database explicitly in Management Studio (right click Databases -> Attach) and then operate on it.

Comment: Thanks I was able to create the bak file via query as from you suggested. However the provider still refuses to accept it. Must be a version compatibility issue? I am using VS 2017

Comment: The version of VS isn't directly relevant, except that it comes with a particular version of SQL Server (VS 2017 uses SQL Server 2016 out of the box). You can check the version with `SELECT @@VERSION`. It is well-known that you cannot attach files or restore backups made by later versions of SQL Server on earlier versions; if that's your issue you'll have to install an appropriate version of SQL Server Express or LocalDB and recreate your database there.

Comment: Thanks finally the bak file was accepted...it was a misunderstanding with the provider

Comment: It's a **backup** file - not a "dump" .....